# from futures to asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, python-asyncio

i am puzzled getting the following to work with asyncio:

the code snippet below is querying a number devices (via snmp) and returns a dictionary, it works fine, but is limited by `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`

```
def do_polling(netelement, snmp_comm):
    msg = {}
    msg.update({
        'bgp'       : do_lookup_bgp(netelement, snmp_comm),
        'iface'     : do_lookup_iface(netelement, snmp_comm),
        'ifidx'     : do_lookup_ifindex(netelement, snmp_comm),
        'agg'       : do_lookup_agg(netelement, snmp_comm),
    })
    return msg

def save(netelement, job):
    data[netelement] = job.result()

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
    for k,v in INFO['dev'].items():
        job = executor.submit(do_polling, k, v['snmp_comm'])
        job.add_done_callback(functools.partial(save, k))
```

so i would like to migrate to the `asyncio` approach by changing like this:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_polling(netelement, snmp_comm):
    msg = {}
    msg['bgp']      = yield from do_lookup_bgp(netelement, snmp_comm)
    msg['iface']    = yield from do_lookup_iface(netelement, snmp_comm)
    msg['ifidx']    = yield from do_lookup_ifindex(netelement, snmp_comm)
    msg['agg']      = yield from do_lookup_agg(netelement, snmp_comm)

@asyncio.coroutine
def schedule(INFO):
    for k,v in INFO['dev'].items():
        asyncio.async(do_polling(k, v))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(schedule)
```

but i am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/ip-spotlight/code/ixmac.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/app/ip-spotlight/code/ixmac.py", line 16, in main
    app.ixmac.initialize.run(INFO)
  File "/home/app/ip-spotlight/code/app/ixmac/initialize.py", line 191, in run
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(schedule)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 353, in run_until_complete
    future = tasks.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 553, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('A Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required')
TypeError: A Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

could you please advise what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using it as a coroutine. You should change the last line to:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(schedule(the_info_variable))
```

Comment: thanks :) do you mind helping me with the `edit` as well

Comment: @iamsterdam What do you mean by `i wait (block) before`

Comment: the `do_polling` function returns a dict that is saved in `data[netelement]`. what i see is happening that `do_polling` calls `do_lookup_bgp` and after that `do_data_wrangling` gets called. what i would like to happen is: `do_polling` to call `do_lookup_bgp`,`do_lookup_iface`,`do_lookup_ifindex`,`do_lookup_agg` for every `netelement` and then `do_data_wrangling` to get called

Comment: my bad :) please ignore the comment above